# LookUpEdit not selecting newly entered value when it's a double

Tags: c#, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

I have 2 LookUpEdit controls from DevExpress on my form.  Both use an `ObservableCollection` as it's datasource, one being of type `string` and the other of type `double`.  The LookUpEdit control has an event called `ProcessNewValue` which fires when, you guessed it, a new value is entered in the control.  I've added some code in this event to add the newly added value to the `ObservableCollection` and it automatically selects it once done.  This works as expected for the `string` LooUpEdit but when I try it with the `double` LookUpEdit`, it adds it to the collection but then it clears out the control.

Here's the code to load the controls, which gets called in `Form_Load()`:

```
    void InitControls()
    {
        double[] issueNumbers = new double[5];

        issueNumbers[0] = 155;
        issueNumbers[1] = 156;
        issueNumbers[2] = 157;
        issueNumbers[3] = 158;
        issueNumbers[4] = 159;

        ObservableCollection<double> issues = new ObservableCollection<double>(issueNumbers);

        lookupIssues.Properties.DataSource = issues;
        DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.LookUpColumnInfoCollection colInfo = lookupIssues.Properties.Columns;
        colInfo.Clear();
        colInfo.Add(new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.LookUpColumnInfo("Column"));
        colInfo[0].Caption = "Issue ID's";

        string[] stringNumbers = Array.ConvertAll<double, string>(issueNumbers, Convert.ToString);
        ObservableCollection<string> issuesString = new ObservableCollection<string>(stringNumbers);

        lookupStringValue.Properties.DataSource = issuesString;
        colInfo.Clear();
        colInfo.Add(new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.LookUpColumnInfo("Column"));
        colInfo[0].Caption = "String Issue ID's";

    }
```

And here's the ProcessNewValue event for both (I've renamed them to try to make it easier to see which does what):

```
    private void OnProcessNewValue_Double(object sender, DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ProcessNewValueEventArgs e)
    {
        ObservableCollection<double> source = (ObservableCollection<double>)(sender as LookUpEdit).Properties.DataSource;

        if (source != null)
        {
            if ((sender as LookUpEdit).Text.Length > 0)
            {
                source.Add(Convert.ToDouble((sender as LookUpEdit).Text));
                (sender as LookUpEdit).Refresh();
            }
        }

        e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void OnProcessNewValue_String(object sender, DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ProcessNewValueEventArgs e)
    {
        ObservableCollection<string> source = (ObservableCollection<string>)(sender as LookUpEdit).Properties.DataSource;

        if (source != null)
        {
            if ((sender as LookUpEdit).Text.Length > 0)
            {
                source.Add((sender as LookUpEdit).Text);
                (sender as LookUpEdit).Refresh();
            }
        }

        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

As you can see, the code it identical with the exception of one converting text to a double before adding it to the collection.

Anyone know why the double value gets added to the collection but the control doesn't automatically select it like it does with a string collection?  I've even tried to hard-code the newly added value right after `e.Handled = true;` but it still doesn't select it.  What's weird is that if I run it through the debugger, I can step through and see that the `lookupIssues` control indeed gets the newly added value AND it's `Text` property is set to it, but as soon as the event terminates, the control clears it out.....really strange.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

BTW, I can add a link to a sample project that duplicates the problem but you would need to have DevExpress v12.2.6 controls installed in order to compile the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posted this to the DevExpress team as well and they were gracious enough to provide the solution:

> I agree that this discrepancy appears confusing as-is. The reason for the discrepancy is LookUpEdit.ProcessNewValueCore makes a call to [RepositoryItemLookUpEdit.GetKeyValueByDisplayValue](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemLookUpEdit_GetKeyValueByDisplayValuetopic) which returns a null value from the LookUpListDataAdapter because no implicit conversion exists from double to string. You may resolve the discrepancy with the following change to your ProcessNewValue handler:

```
private void OnProcessNewValue_Double(object sender, DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ProcessNewValueEventArgs e) 
{
    ObservableCollection<double> source = (ObservableCollection<double>)(sender as LookUpEdit).Properties.DataSource;

    if (source != null) {
        if ((sender as LookUpEdit).Text.Length > 0) {
            double val = Convert.ToDouble((sender as LookUpEdit).Text);
            source.Add(val);
            e.DisplayValue = val;
            (sender as LookUpEdit).Refresh();
        }
    }        
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

The control now behaves as expected.  I hope this can help someone else out :)